# Custom GridSplitter not resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, wpf-style, gridsplitter

I want to template my `GridSplitter` with some custom code, but it seems to stop working when I overwrite `ControlTemplate`.

My code looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Vertical_GridSplitter" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridSplitter}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">

                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Width="3"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>                
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm sure the problem is here, not in the `View` itself, because if I use the default `GridSplitter` without my styling it works just fine. With my code, styling gets applied, mouse cursor changes to arrows like it should, but clicking on the `GridSplitter` and dragging it does nothing...

Comment: Get rid of the Margin setter and Width="3" ? And please provide a repo if your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Claiming that "it doesn't work" without providing a repo doesn't make much sense I am afraid.

Comment: What will it change? I want GridSplitter to look like this. As I said, styling gets applied correctly, it's just that it doesn't work like GridSplitter should (doesn't provide a feature of resizing other content by dragging it).

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself. The problem was here:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
```

Should be:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```

Comment: My point is that you haven't included anything but a Style in your question. There is no sample of how the actual GridSplitter is used in the Grid. I posted a link in my first comment. I encourage you to read it. Good luck and have a nice day.